# Format C# Source Code with Hyperlinks to Reference Library Documentation

Tags: c#, parsing, syntax-highlighting

I'm wondering if anyone has done this already.

I want to format C# source code in HTML. But with a twist! I want to turn the names of all types and methods that appear in the code into hyperlinks to the MSDN Library documentation of the types and methods.

To do a good job, the data types of variables and expressions needs to be known, just like how the C# compiler does it. So it's a tall order. If something like this is not available, please point me to any free libraries that can generate a parsed tree of the C# source code in sufficient detail to do this task. (In fact, I'd like to know about such a standalone parser library even if the full solution I am asking for already exists.)

This kind of utility might benefit blogs and forums -- maybe even Stack Overflow!

Comment: You know you can press F12 to go to the definition which will contain the comments that are generated for display in the MSDN Library, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Docu](http://docu.jagregory.com/)? It's an open source library that converts .net documentation into HTML documents.

Comment: I'm not trying to convert .NET documentation into HTML. I am trying to convert method names *in the source itself* into hyperlinks to the existing MSDN Library documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [Visual Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx).